# Not able to perform Touch To Call functionality in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, phone-call, android-relativelayout

I have implemented 'Touch To Call' functionality in my app and I have 3 buttons from which I directly make calls just by clicking on button. I have made calls on 100,101,112 numbers. The code is working perfectly for 100 and 101 but when I click on 112 button then it re directs me to keypad screen where I can make calls instead to making direct call. This is only happening with 112 number. I am just fed up with this. Please help.

**Code for the same**

```
       @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.imgBell112:
            checkCallPermission("112");
            break;

    }
}


public void checkCallPermission(String mobile) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mobile));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.kentoren_office_details_msg), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, CALL_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mobile));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `112` is an emergency number in some countries (Germany for example) and they prevent the 'direct calling' to these numbers. You can verify that using the number 911.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission for emergency number Manifest Permission `CALL_PRIVILEGED` in manifest

Dial like this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel://911");
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,uri);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

Hope maybe useful to you!

Comment: Still not working. This code also re directs to dial screen not making direct call